# Gridview with Gallery behavior?

Tags: android, gridview, gallery

I wanna create a gridview which behave like gallery, i mean when i press down, all the grid move and the highlight stay fix (in the vertical moves), otherwise i want to create a vertical
gallery with multiple columns.
I tried this given that my gridview have 4 column.

```
gridview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            gridview.setSelection(firstVisibleItem+4);



        }
    });
```

It doesn't work, i am beginner in Android/java and i want to learn and i need help.

```
this is my xml file.
                   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_film1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="65dp" android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp" 
     android:divider="#00000000"
    android:scrollbars="none" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" android:gravity="center" />
```

There are not error, the gridview scroll but not the scroll style i want, check the grid in the middle here, all the grid move and the highlight stay fix [clicker tv](http://tv.clicker.com/)

Comment: So what's your question?  and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need help to implement this custom widget, i need an example for a vertical gallery with multi-column or a gridview that scroll vertically conserving the highlight position.

Comment: like this grid in the middle, check the behavior [link](http://tv.clicker.com/)

Comment: Post your XML and more code, specifically where you're initialising the gridview, etc.  Also, what do you mean by "not work"? What error messages are you getting?  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: i edited my post, no  error messages, but the grid start scrolling when highlight is at the end of screen, i want the highlight fix in the middle and the grid move on scroll like this grids [link](http://tv.clicker.com)

Comment: There is no solution for that?

Comment: How many rows are visible on screen?  And where are you setting the initial highlight?  You have to set the selected item in the beginning when you initialise the gridview.  At the same time, set your first visible item to 1, then in the onScroll check whether the first visible item has changed - if yes, then move the selection by the same number of items as the change in the first visible item.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `GridView` and `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` classes.  Essentially, you'll create your grid view of images, then set it's `OnScrollListener`.  You'll need to keep track of the current first visible items.  In the listener's `onScroll` method implementation, check whether first visible item has changed - if yes, then change your selection in the grid view accordingly.

Try doing some research, try writing the code - then, if you encounter problems, post your code here and we'll try to help.  However don't just expect people to do the work for you.

Comment: i tried some ways but it doesn't work, i edited my post, please help.